# Conversion from WAV to MP3 and the Patent

Tags: android, mp3, wav

I have read regarding MP3 and its patent. I'm confuse as to which part of using MP3 I can be sued for. 
Like if I create and Android App which record WAV and I want to convert it to MP3, can I get myself to a lot of trouble?
How about those Apps in Play Store which offers converting to MP3, are they paying too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the forum for a question like this... The short answer is if you're making money you have to pay. I don't think they are going to get bent out of shape if you aren't intaking any revenue, but tread carefully. You can read about MP3 royalties rates [here](http://mp3licensing.com/royalty/).